# Simple React-Redux component not updating

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm just starting to learn redux with react and I've been having this simple issue for a while now that I can't figure out. I have a button that dispatches an action to increment a value, and the action goes through and updates the state, but no change is ever reflected in the component. What am I doing wrong here?

```
const ACTION = 'ACTION';
const defaultState = {
  value: 5
};
const doAction = ()=>{
  return {
    type: ACTION
  };
};

const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  let update = Object.assign({}, state);
  switch(action.type){
    case ACTION:
      update.value = state.value + 1;
      return update;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const store = Redux.createStore(reducer);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e){
    this.props.doAction();
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div id='app'>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
        <p>{this.props.value}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;

const mapStateToProps = (state)=> {
  return {
    value: state.value
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    doAction: () => {
      dispatch(doAction())
    }
  };
}

const Container = ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

class AppWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Container />
      </Provider>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<AppWrapper />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I think instead of ```update.value = state.value + 1;
      return update;```  use `{...state, {value: state + 1}}`

Comment: While there are some flaws in your code, it is indeed runnable, check if you installed all dependencies and imported them correctly https://codesandbox.io/s/88przy8ro0

Comment: @sn42 I'm using codepen to write this right now and the only dependency I haven't included is react-scripts. Is there anything in that library that would affect my code? And also could you elaborate on the flaws in my code? I'm still learning.

Answer (score 1):

### Issue regarding codepen.io

Codepen provides the newest version of react-redux by default, unluckily it is a test version (`5.1.0-test.1`) currently. Change the external script url of react-redux to `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/5.0.7/react-redux.js` and your pen should be working: [Working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QBdXxd)

I don't recommend codepen for react development. Consider `create-react-app` or [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/) if it has to be an online ide. You really need more than one editable file to structure your actions, reducers and components.

### How to improve your code

In your reducer you create a copy of the previous state in every case, even when you return the previous state. Try this instead:

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION:
      return { ...state, value: state.value + 1 };
      // Alternative: Object.assign({}, state, { value: state.value + 1 });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This will ensure you create objects only if needed. You could have returned `{ value: state.value + 1 }` for this simple state shape, the spread operator or `Object.assign(...)` are a valuable tool when you want to clone the previous state and change only some (or delete) properties without affecting others.

Furthermore you can refactor your app to a functional react component:

```
const App = (props) => (
  <div>
    <button onClick={props.action}>Click</button>
    <p>{props.value}</p>
  </div>
);
```

And connect the App to redux with:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  value: state.value
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  action: () => dispatch(doAction())
});

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Note that i stick to your component names here.

### Where to go from here...

If you are interested in a bigger example i have created [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/qxx1p03jq4) which features routing, fake authentication, a todo list and a simple counter. Redux devtools is integrated, too. Just open the browser extension on [this site](https://qxx1p03jq4.codesandbox.io/) to inspect the store and the dispatched actions.